# Number of ways a multiple choice exam can be answered if no two consecutive answers are the same

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many different ways can you answer a 7- question multiple choice exam (with 3 choices) if you know that no two consecutive answers are the same?

Answer (score 1):

By 'no two consecutive answers are the same' I assume you mean the answers are lettered (a through c, for example) and that, 'a' for example, could not be the answer twice in a row.

In that case, I think you could pick 1 out of 3 answers for the first question and then for the remaining six questions you would only have 2 choices since the answer to the previous question would eliminate one of the choices so the answer would be $$3\times2^{6}=192$$

Comment: May I recommend using either `\times` or `\cdot` as the multiplication operator in the $\TeX$-formatting rather than `*`?

Comment: Sure, I went with `\times` there does not seem to be a lot of love in the LaTeX community for `\cdot` from what I have seen.

Comment: @JasonBoyd I do not think the answer is correct. At the third question, you could answer with any of a, b, c.

Comment: @phatty But the answer to the second question must be a, b or c.  Whatever the answer to question two is, three cannot be that answer.  So that leaves two possibilities for question three.